# Ruby on Rails: How to validate nested attributes on certain condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have these models:

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :people
  has_one     :address, :as         => :addressable,
                        :dependent  => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :organisation_id, :address_attributes

  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :organisation
  has_one     :address, :as         => :addressable,
                        :dependent  => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true

  # These two methods seem to have no effect at all!
  validates_presence_of :organisation,  :unless => "address.present?"
  validates_associated  :address,       :unless => "organisation.present?"

end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  validates_presence_of :line1, :line2, :city, :zip

end
```

...and these views:

**_fields.html.erb**:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<fieldset>
<div class="left">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :email %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :organisation_id %><br/>
    <%= f.select(:organisation_id, current_user.organisation_names, {:include_blank => "--- None ---"}, :id => 'organisation_select') %>
</div>
</fieldset>

<%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
  <%= render 'shared/address', :f => address %>
<% end %>
```

**_address.html.erb:**

```
<fieldset id="address_fields">
<div>
    <%= f.label :line1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :line1 %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :line2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :line2 %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :zip %>
    <%= f.text_field :zip %>
</div>  
<div>
    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
</div>  
</fieldset>
```

**people_controller.rb**:

```
def new
  puts params.inspect
  @person = Person.new(:organisation_id => params[:organisation_id])
  @person.build_address
  @title = "New person"
end

{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"people"}

def edit
  puts params.inspect
  @title = @person.name
end

{"action"=>"edit", "id"=>"69", "controller"=>"people"}

def create
  puts params.inspect
  if params[:organisation_id]
    @person = current_user.organisations.build_person(params[:person])
  else
    @person = current_user.people.build(params[:person])
  end
  if @person.save
    flash[:success] = "Person created."
    redirect_to people_path
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end

{"commit"=>"Create", "action"=>"create", "person"=>{"last_name"=>"Doe", "organisation_id"=>"9", "email"=>"john.doe@email.com", "first_name"=>"John", "address_attributes"=>{"city"=>"Chicago", "zip"=>"12345", "line2"=>"Apt 1", "line1"=>"1 Main Street"}}, "authenticity_token"=>"Jp3XVLbA3X1SOigPezYFfEol0FGjcMHRTy6jQeM1OuI=", "controller"=>"people", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

Inside my `Person` model I need to make sure that only if a person's `organisation_id` is blank, that person's address fields have to be present.

I tried something like this:

```
validates :address, :presence => true, :if => "organisation_id.blank?"
```

But it's not working.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you use chrome, be sure to install: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/diff-for-gistgithub/ekibhngllckenihijddjkmehiocljcpc It will allow you to diff the various gists we have made.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First of all, I want to be sure that you mean `blank?` rather than `present?`.  Typically, I see this:

```
validate :address, :presence_of => true, :if => 'organisation.present?'
```

Meaning, you only want to validate address if organisation is also present.

Regarding, `:accepts_nested_attributes_for`, are you using this feature by passing in nested form attributes, or some such thing?  I just want to make sure you absolutely need to use this functionality.  If you are not actually dealing with nested form attributes, you can implement cascading validation using:

```
validates_associated :address
```

If you do need to use `:accepts_nested_attributes`, be sure to check out the `:reject_if` parameter.  Basically, you can reject adding an attribute (and it's descendants) altogether if certain conditions apply:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :no_organisation

def no_organisation(attributes)
  attributes[:organisation_id].blank?
end
```

Now, if none of the above apply, let's take a look at your syntax:

It should work, `:if/:unless` take [symbols, strings and procs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation).  You don't need to point to the foreign_key, but can simplify by pointing to:

```
:if => "organisation.blank?"
```

You have other validations in the Address model, correct?  Is Address being validated when you don't want it to?  Or is Address not being validated?  I can help you test it out in the console if you can give me some additional details.

---

1. To make things easier for myself re: mass-assignment, I changed the rails config: `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false`
2. I created [a gist for you to follow along](https://gist.github.com/3853702)
3. I have a sample project as well.  Let me know if you are interested.

   Basic points:
4. Added the following to Person to ensure that either Org or Address are valid:

   `validates_presence_of :organisation, :unless => "address.present?"`
   `validates_associated :address, :unless => "organisation.present?"`
5. Added validation to Address to trigger errors when Org is not present:
   `validates_presence_of :line1, :line2, :city, :zip`

   I was able to produce the requirements you are seeking.  Please look [at the gist I created](https://gist.github.com/3853702) where I have a full console test plan.

---

I added [a controller file to the previous gist](https://gist.github.com/3853702#file_controller.rb).

Overview:

1. All you should need to create the person is:
   `@person = current_user.people.build(params[:person])`
2. :organisation_id will always be found off of the :person param node, like so:
   `params[:person][:organisation_id]`
   So you're if will never be true.

---

I updated the gist with the necessary changes to [the controller](https://gist.github.com/3853702#file_person_controller.rb), [the model](https://gist.github.com/3853702#file_models.rb) and [the form](https://gist.github.com/3853702#file__fields.html.erb).

Overview:

1. You need to cleanup your controller. You are using `accepts_nested_attribute`, so in the :create, you only care about `params[:person]`.  Additionally, in the `render :new`, you need to setup any instance variables that the partial will use.  This does **NOT** go back through the `:new` action.  The `:new` and `:edit` actions also need to be simplified.
2. Your Person model needs to use the `:reject_if` argument because the Address fields are coming back to the :create action as `:address_attributes => {:line1 => '', :line2 => '', etc}`.  you only want to create the association if any have values.  Then your `validates_presence_of` for `:organisation` will work just fine.
3. Your form needs to pass the organisation id to the controller, rather than the organisation names

   It's all in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/3853702)

---

Should be [the final gist](https://gist.github.com/3879505).

Overview:

1. Add the following to your edit action right after building the @person:

   @person.build_address if @person.address.nil?
   This ensure that you have the address inputs, even if the @person.address does not exist.  It doesn't exist, because of the :reject_if condition on accepts_nested_attributes
2. I DRYed up the :reject_if as follows.  It's a little hacky, but has some utility:

   ```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :attributes_blank?

   def attributes_blank?(attrs)  
     attrs.except('id').values.all?(&:blank?)  
   end
   ```

   a. `attrs` -> the result of params[:person][:address]
     b. `.except('id')` -> return all key-values except for 'id'
     c. `.values` -> return all values from a hash as an array
     d. `.all?` -> do all elements in the array satisfy the following check
     e. `&:blank` -> ruby shorthand for a block, like this: `all?{ |v| v.blank? }`

Comment: By the way, I kept typing 'organisation' as 'organization', so there might be some typos.

Comment: Hello Matt, thanks for your kind help. I extended my initial answer above a bit and also posted the view code. Indeed I am using `:accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the Person model, so that it also accepts the address data for the person in question. Is that not a good idea? To be honest I failed to get your code working, even though  it's definitely a lot better than mine.

Comment: Basically, when a new person is created that person must belong to an organisation. Only if is does *not* (i.e. if no option is selected in the organisation select box), that person's nested address attributes will have to be filled in by the user. Unfortunately, I find this really difficult to realise, so I hope you can help me with it.

Comment: Hello Matt. Thanks a lot!! I was able to get your code working on my console and learned a lot just by doing that. I only made some slight changes to it because my Person and Organisation models both required a `user_id` as well. The 5 tests you created all pass as expected. p, p2, p3 return `true` while p4 and p5 return `false`. I guess that's the outcome that you expected?

Comment: The problem now is that except of the first one, none of the scenarios work like that when I create a new person in the browser. I get an error message whenever I leave the address fields empty, no matter if an organisation is selected in the dropdown menu or not. So does this mean that my controller is faulty? I wonder if the `@person.build_address` line causes the validation to run every time? But I also kind of need it because else no address fields will be displayed in my form at all.

Comment: Can you add the following line at the top of you controller action and add the output in your post: puts params.inspect

Comment: Yep. I'll have a solution for you shortly.

Comment: Hello Matt. Thanks for your help. Indeed my controller code was a bit silly; I changed it accordingly. I studied your code very carefully and also ran the `test_person` test. I cannot find anything wrong with it though. Everything behaves as it should, except for the `Address` model whose validation cannot be skipped. It seems that due to the line `@person.build_address` in my `new` action, Rails considers the address as being *present* and thus the validation method `validates_associated  :address, :unless => "organisation.present?"` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Actually, I spent hours this morning trying to get the two validation methods in the Person model to work. I also tried the `lambda` and `Proc` syntax, but to no avail. The validation methods inside the `Address` model do **always** get fired, no matter what I do in the `Person` model. This is really weird...

Comment: OK, I just updated the Model code in my initial question above, just to provide some more info on what I have.

Comment: Their are a few things that I see that are wrong.  I will update in a bit.

Comment: OK, it works now. This line did the trick: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:line1].blank? && a[:line2].blank? && a[:city].blank? && a[:zip].blank? }` I also created a [new gist](https://gist.github.com/3878726).

Comment: One little problem that's left is that when I edit a previously created person and remove all that person's address fields, all fields appear filled in again after hitting the `Update` button. But that should be relatively easy to fix in my controller code. By the way, have I said "**Thanks**" yet? You really saved me an awful lot of work and I learned a lot about Rails along the way.

Comment: No problem.  It's my pleasure.  I have an additional gist for you with some notes.

Comment: @MattDressel I have a related problem, maybe you can give your 2 cents? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867452/rails-validate-presence-of-at-least-one-has-one-association-of-a-group

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
validates :address, :presence => true, :if => organisation_id.nil?
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I get an `undefined method key? for nil:NilClass` error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it would be the negation of that (`!organisation_id.nil`). Regardless I would go with Matt's answer

Answer (score 0):

A more simple approach might be to add a custom validator. It's super easy, and you don't have to stumble on syntax or try to figure out why Rails' magic isn't working.

> Inside my Person model I need to make sure that only if a person's organisation_id is blank, that person's address fields have to be present.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :address_if_organisation_id_is_present

  private

  def address_if_organisation_id_is_present
    return true unless organisation_id
    errors.add(:address, "cannot be blank") unless address
  end
end
```

Adding to a model's errors will prevent it from saving. Note: you may wish to use `address.blank?` or `address.empty?` as discussed in other answers, but you can define this for the behavior you'd like.